# How do you calculate reference line of average in tableau?

Tags: average, tableau-api

I am a new bee to tableau. I am watching the below tutorial.

http://www.tableau.com/learn/tutorials/on-demand/nested-lod-expressions?signin=85b3fd2f256e285b0f60efaf2798d48d

So in the example it is calculating (0+1+2...41)/40 and the average 20.125.I know that is wrong as it is not considering the count of customer ID.  But i don't understand how it is calculating 16.25 ? PLEASE explain the mathematical formula to do if i don't want to use tableau and get 16.25 ???

Please i have been banging my head all day

[image]

Comment: Looking for clarification here: Are you just asking for someone to explain the formula in that image? Or are you trying to understand what the two different numbers there are? Or are you asking how to get those reference lines?

Comment: i am trying to ask for someone to explain the formula in that image? and  trying to understand how did the 16.20 got there ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a rather roundabout way of calculating weighted average! If, using the Distinct count of Customer ID as the weight, you get a weighted average of 16.20. Put this data into excel and see for yourself:

Col1: Number of Orders per Customer
Col 2: Avg. Nested LOD
Col 3: Distinct count of Customer ID (Weights)

Wtd. Avg =SUMPRODUCT(Col1,Col3)/SUM(Col3)

```
1   16.19685535 10
2   16.19685535 24
3   16.19685535 62
4   16.19685535 110
5   16.19685535 110
6   16.19685535 117
7   16.19685535 112
8   16.19685535 96
9   16.19685535 74
10  16.19685535 37
11  16.19685535 21
12  16.19685535 13
13  16.19685535 7
14  16.19685535 4
15  16.19685535 7
16  16.19685535 7
17  16.19685535 10
18  16.19685535 17
19  16.19685535 35
20  16.19685535 35
21  16.19685535 37
22  16.19685535 49
23  16.19685535 43
24  16.19685535 62
25  16.19685535 69
26  16.19685535 63
27  16.19685535 58
28  16.19685535 50
29  16.19685535 56
30  16.19685535 43
31  16.19685535 38
32  16.19685535 36
33  16.19685535 20
34  16.19685535 18
35  16.19685535 10
36  16.19685535 12
37  16.19685535 11
38  16.19685535 4
39  16.19685535 2
41  16.19685535 1


Average 20.525  
Weighted Average    16.19685535
```

Just copy paste the data above as a text file and then open with Excel, importing it as a 'fixed width' text file.

Comment: Thanks .. I did that into excel and verified the results ... so the total of weighted average is 1590 same as distinct count of customer id 1590 ..

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'total of weighted average'..I'm assuming you mean the sum of the weights...then yes, it's the same as COUNT DISTINCT of Customer ID. Essentially, the wtd. avg. answers the question: 'What is the average number of orders placed by a typical customer?'

Comment: sorry 2 question 1) i am really interested in knowing how would you do it without the ans (16.20) ? 2) just to understand the  results  -- 1 16.19685535 10 and - 0.617403797 (lowest) -- 25 16.19685535 69 106.5021551 (highest) ... so the result is trying to say that the lowest average (probability ?)is that one customer will place 10 orders and the highest average is that customers will place 62 orders ?

Comment: @harshilbhatt I'm not sure I understand what you are asking..how would you do what without the answer? There is no probability involved here. Also not sure, where you are getting these numbers and what they mean...

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29570362/adding-reference-line-for-weighted-average-in-tableau for creating a wtd.avg. line

Comment: these number are from what you gave me =SUMPRODUCT(A1,C1)/SUM(B1)

Comment: Look again: you may be applying the wrong formula. Assuming you copied the data correctly, it should be SUMPRODUCT(A1,C1)/SUM(C1). If you are unsure what/how re wtd. averages, google it up.